# How to make scp respect umask

Tags: scp, umask

My `scp` doesn't respect **umask** setting of the user it's sending files to. Is there a setting somewhere or should I use a different solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The umask, in the way you mean it, is a property of the login shell. It is set in `.profile` or one of its relatives. Since `scp` doesn't log in interactively, it doesn't run any of these scripts, so it doesn't get the umask setting you've defined there.

The closest thing I can think of to what you want is to set the permissions appropriately on the file locally, then use the `-p` option to `scp` to preserve the file modes.

You might also find `rsync` helpful. If you use its `-a` option, it will preserve almost all attributes of a file when copying, including permissions and modes.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer over on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/228396/how-to-setup-sshs-umask-for-all-type-of-connections/229944#229944) it looks like the best way to make this happen is to introduce [pam_umask](http://linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_umask.html) into the target systems authentication sequence.

Comment: I want it to be set only for a specific user on the target system.

Comment: or adjust `/etc/login.defs` which pam_umask uses