# scp and umask setting

Tags: scp, umask

How do I make SCP respect umask ?

I've tried adding this

```
Subsystem      sftp  internal-sftp -u 0002
```

in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

and

```
session    optional     pam_umask.so umask=0002
```

in /etc/pam.d/sshd

Any other things to try?

each time scp creates the file as 644 instead of 664 as the umask would suggest

Comment: SFTP has nothing to do with scp. So your configuration in sshd_config is irrelevant.

Comment: So can i set the value for scp in the sshd config file in a similar way ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16969/how-to-make-scp-respect-umask

Comment: Please give an example of the operation you are attempting.  The solutions are probably different depending on whether you are copying to local or to remote.

Comment: @JoeAtzberger scp local remote. remote dir is sticky bitted for group and should be 664 or 775 as standard

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate user for `scp` on the remote side, and set their `umask` through [`login.conf(5)`](http://mdoc.su/o/login.conf.5) (if on OpenBSD).

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, `scp` does not initialize a shell, thus don't source any file such as `.profile`, `.bashrc`, `/etc/profile`.

So the only way of doing this seems to use the pam module `pam_umask.so`. But it will be applied to all users (unless you use a more complicated PAM setup)

The file `/etc/pam.d/sshd` is probably the best place to do it, if you want to limit this behavior to ssh sessions :

```
session optional pam_umask.so umask=0007
```

Comment: This was mentioned in the question, It didnt work for me. though im not sure about the umask 0007 ?

Comment: My bad… I overlooked the question. Did you try to debug the module execution?

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to use something better to this like rsync command.

Taken from man:

> Some of the additional features of rsync are:
>
> ```
>    support for copying links, devices, owners, groups, and permissions
> ```
>
> Syntax:
>
> ```
>    Local:  rsync [OPTION...] SRC... [DEST]
>
>    Access via remote shell:
>      Pull: rsync [OPTION...] [USER@]HOST:SRC... [DEST]
>      Push: rsync [OPTION...] SRC... [USER@]HOST:DEST
> ```

To preserve modification times, access times, and modes from the original file you can use -p after scp. But this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: I dont want to preserve information, I want to have it set as 664 instead of 644

Answer (score -3):

what you are trying to do you can't achive with umask try to  mask instead.

umask acts like this:

- situation per default folders are created with 775 and files with 664 (owner/user read+write group read+write others read - folders also have set traverse for user group and others)

if one does not like this one can cut the roghts by e.g setting a umask like 027 wich means user no changes group -2 (default minus write) others -7 (default minus read/write/execute(traverse if folder)

to be simple: umask 027 ~= chmod g-w o-rwx

so with umask u can only lower/cut rights

to add/higher rights use mask

if you need to know more please read the man pages of umask and mask or have a look at the entry on wikipedia http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask

Comment: There is no `mask` command. `umask` is the right way to set the default mask. Besides, if you set the mask with `umask 0000`, new files will be created with `666` as permissions, and directories with `777`. So this command does allow a higher permission than the default one.